# Как анимировать треугольники в PlaneBufferGeometry?

Tags: three.js, webgl, glsl

Как я могу анимировать или просто взаимодействовать с этими треугольниками: https://jsfiddle.net/t2bjzc8r/1/ ? Я планирую наложить текстуру - фотографию на PlaneBufferGeometry и разбить ее на эти треугольники(будто стеклянная фотография разбивается на части), но я не могу понять, как я мог бы управлять ими. [cutt.ly/8fJRJHG](http://cutt.ly/8fJRJHG) - как пример (нашел в гугле)

```
let renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material;

init();
animate();


function init(){
//SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x09090C );

//CAMERA
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth /       window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 3;

//scene.add(camera);

//Plane
geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 10, 10 );

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  wireframe: true
});
let plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( plane );


//RENDERER
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {

camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

render();
}
function render() {
renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Comment: вопрос слишком общий, что Вам необходимо ?

Comment: Да, хотелось бы знать - что подразумевается под "анимировать" и "взаимодействовать"

Comment: Я планирую наложить текстуру - фотографию на PlaneBufferGeometry и разбить ее на эти треугольники(будто стеклянная фотография разбивается на части), но я не могу понять, как я мог бы управлять ими. https://cutt.ly/8fJRJHG - пример (нашел в гугле)

Comment: Есть вот такой пример: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing

Comment: Для пущей рандомизации треугольников, можно использовать библиотеку триангуляции типа Delaunator.js: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-delaunator/4952?u=prisoner849

Answer (score 2):

В общем и целом, вариантов создания данного эффекта - масса.
Дабы не лезть в дебри буферной геометрии, инстансов и кастомных шейдеров, можно пойти по самому простому пути: разбить плоскость на треугольники, где каждый треугольник - отдельный меш, который можно анимировать отдельно, используя Tween.js или GSAP (последний сейчас все больше входит в моду в связке с Three.js)

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.5.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.120.1/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.120.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 15, 30);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// плоскость и ее расщепление на треугольники
let division = 5;
let divisionStep = 1 / division;
let g = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, division, division);
// чуток рандомизируем точки внути плоскости и пересчитаем UV координаты
let pos = g.getAttribute("position");
let uv = g.getAttribute("uv");
let v3 = new THREE.Vector3(); // временный вектор для всяких нужд
for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
  v3.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  if (Math.max(Math.abs(v3.x), Math.abs(v3.y)) < 0.5){
    pos.setXYZ(
      i,
      v3.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * divisionStep * 0.75,
      v3.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * divisionStep * 0.75,
      0
    );
  }
}
g.translate(0.5, 0.5, 0);
for (let i = 0; i < uv.count; i++){
  v3.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  uv.setXY(i, v3.x, v3.y);
}
g.translate(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
g.scale(10, 10, 1);

// разбиваем на осколки

let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false, map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg")});
let pieces = [];
let faces = g.index.count / 3;
let tempTri = new THREE.Triangle();
let center = new THREE.Vector3();
for(let i = 0; i < faces; i++){
  let a = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, g.index.getX(i * 3 + 0));
  let b = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, g.index.getX(i * 3 + 1));
  let c = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, g.index.getX(i * 3 + 2));
  let pg = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([a,b,c]);
  tempTri.set(a, b, c);
  tempTri.getMidpoint(center);
  pg.translate(-center.x, -center.y, -center.z);
 
  let uvs = [];
  uvs.push(
    uv.getX(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 0)),
    uv.getY(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 0)),
    uv.getX(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 1)),
    uv.getY(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 1)),
    uv.getX(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 2)),
    uv.getY(g.index.getX(i * 3 + 2))
  );
  //console.log(uvs);
  pg.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
  let p = new THREE.Mesh(pg, m);
  p.userData.finish = {
    position: new THREE.Vector3().copy(center),
    rotation: new THREE.Euler().copy(p.rotation)
  };
  p.userData.start = {
    position: new THREE.Vector3().random().subScalar(0.5).multiplyScalar(2 * 25),
    rotation: new THREE.Euler(
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 10 + 5,
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 10 + 5,
      Math.random() * Math.PI * 10 + 5
    )
  }
  p.position.copy(center);

  pieces.push(p);
  scene.add(p);
}


// анимация

pieces.forEach(piece => {
  let duration = Math.random() * 5 + 1;
  let p = piece.userData.finish.position;
  let r = piece.userData.finish.rotation;
  
  gsap.to(piece.position.copy(piece.userData.start.position), {x: p.x, y: p.y, z: p.z, duration: duration
}).play();

  gsap.to(piece.rotation.copy(piece.userData.start.rotation), {x: r.x, y: r.y, z: r.z, duration: duration}).play();

});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Насколько мне известно, сделать это на шейдерах не сложно - всего пара строчек кода. Пример: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2020/08/27/experimental-triangle-image-transitions-with-webgl/  Но в шейдерах я еще профан, поэтому хотел узнать, можно ли сделать похожую анимацию на PlaneBufferGeometry и треугольников, которые она нам дает.

Comment: @Никита Особенно проста строчка `vec3 newPosition = move(position, progress);` за которой скрывается много интересного :) Шейдеры - не что-то сложное для понимания (хотя и да - сложное), но упомянутая "The Book of Shaders" обязательна к прочтению. Akella (Юрий), кстати, иногда заходит на официальный дискорд канал и форум по Three.js, и ютуб-канал у него отличный, всячески рекомендую.